# Jenkins Pipeline - attachmentsPattern (outside workspace)

Tags: jenkins

GENERATES REPORT FILE into /tmp (outside Jenkins Workspace)

```
def publisher = LastChanges.getLastChangesPublisher null, "SIDE", "LINE", true, true, "", "", "", "", ""
publisher.publishLastChanges()
def htmlDiff = publisher.getHtmlDiff()
writeFile file: "/tmp/${APPNAME}-${ENVIRONMENT}-build.diff.html", text: htmlDiff
```

ATTACHEMENT ANT BLOB

```
attachmentsPattern: "/tmp/*${APPNAME}-${ENVIRONMENT}-build.diff.html",
```

ERROR

```
ERROR: Error accessing files to attach: Expecting Ant GLOB pattern, but saw '/tmp/*/tmp/aaa-development-build.diff.html'. See http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html for syntax
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using dir

```
dir ("tmp"){
  attachmentsPattern: "**/*${APPNAME}-${ENVIRONMENT}-build.diff.html",
}
```